# Gulp / SCSS to CSS Working (but not working)

Tags: sass, gulp

I REALLY hope this isnt a duplicate but i have searched countless posts on here and cant find this specific issue, hopefully the stackoverflow community can help

I am new to Gulp and Sass and am in the process of setting up a simple template to experiement and prepare future projects, but ive hit a snag

i have the following folder structure for testing (il adjust this when its all working to be better)

```
Template
-- node_modules
-- stylesheets
-----test.scss
-----test.css (generated by the gulpfile.js)
gulpfile.js
package.json
```

my gulp file is as follows, a simple watch on test.scss to create and update test.css

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('styles', function() {
    return gulp.src('stylesheets/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError));
});

//Watch task
gulp.task('default',function() {
    gulp.watch('stylesheets/**/*.scss', ['styles']);
});
```

Now when i run gulp and save a style in test.scss i get something like this in cmd

```
Starting 'styles'...
Finished 'styles' after 49 ms
```

So i believe there are no errors, however when i look in the test.css file that is created / updated there are no styles!

it does however copy over comments... so if i put in /* comment */ into test.scss then sure enough /* comment */ appears in text.css

gulp-sass installed succesfully but im really confused as to what im missing

Thanks in advance

James

P.S, versions of things etc, i also have a XAMPP webserver set up locally

```
Node => v6.11.1,
gulp => CLI version 1.3.1, Local version 3.9.1,
ruby => 2.4.1p111,
sass => 3.5.1 (Bleeding Edge)
npm => 3.10.10
```

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
gulp.task('styles', function() {
    return gulp.src('stylesheets/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError));
});
```

should be

```
gulp.task('styles', function() {
    return gulp.src('stylesheets/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./stylesheets'));
});
```